# How does Keycloak protect the private key used to sign JWT tokens with Quarkus?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using keycloak in the last version with quarkus, and i am trying to get or at least to know where keycloak save the private key to sign the JWT tokens and how keycloak protect it, i see a lot of things in the documentation, but is confusing for me, i'm not sure if the private key is in a keystore file, because if I have dockers with many instance is necessary have sincronized the key in all instances then i don't believe that the key is in file system.

Thanks a lot.

know where keycloak save the JWT token private key